# Problem with "does not evaluate to a numeric scalar at the coordinate {2.75,3/2}, but it is outside domain

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

[image]

Problem with "does not evaluate to a numeric scalar at the coordinate {2.75,3/2}, but that point is outside domain. How can I fix it??

```
Remove["Global`*"] ;
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
HeatTransferModelAxisymmetric[T_, {r_, z_}, k_, ρ_, Cp_,Velocity_, Source_] := Module[{V, Q}, V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 0, Velocity.Inactive[Grad][T, {r, z}]]; Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];(1 - (r)^2 - ((1 - 0.5^2)/(Log[1/0.5]))*Log[1/r])*D[T, z] +1/r*D[-k*r*D[T, r], r] + D[-k*D[T, z], z] + V - Q]
op = HeatTransferModelAxisymmetric[T[r, z], {r, z}, k, ρ, Cp,"NoFlow", "NoSource"]
parameters = {k -> 10, d -> 10};
Subscript[Γ, flux] = NeumannValue[40*(500 - T[r, z]), r == 2.5];
Subscript[Γ, temp] = DirichletCondition[T[r, z] == 1200, r == 1];
Subscript[Γ, enter] = DirichletCondition[T[r, z] == 800, z == 0];
Ω = Rectangle[{1, 0}, {2.5, 3}];
pde = {op == Subscript[Γ, flux],Subscript[Γ, temp],Subscript[Γ, enter]} /. parameters; Tfun =NDSolveValue[pde, T, {r, z} ∈ Ω];
MassTransferModelAxisymmetric[c_, {r_, z_}, d_, Velocity_, Source_] :=Module[{V, Q},V = If[Velocity === "NoFlow", 0, Velocity.Inactive[Grad][c, {r, z}]];Q = If[Source === "NoSource", 0, Source];(1 - (r)^2 - ((1 - 0.5^2)/(Log[1/0.5]))*Log[1/r])*D[c, z] + 1/r*D[-d*r*D[c, r], r] + D[-d*D[c, z], z] + 4.67`*^14*Exp[-36635/(Tfun[r, z])]*c + V - Q]
op2 = MassTransferModelAxisymmetric[c[r, z], {r, z}, d, "NoFlow","NoSource"]
Subscript[Γ, enter] = DirichletCondition[c[r, z] == 800, z == 0];
pde2 = {op2 == Subscript[Γ, enter]} /.parameters;cfun=NDSolveValue[pde2, c, {r, z} ∈ Ω];
```

Comment: Please, share the code as a text, rather than the image.

Comment: I just edited it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have run across a bug, but hard coding the convective and source terms into your `HeatTransferModelAxisymmetric` and `MassTransferModelAxisymmetric` I would consider bad practice since those functions support the addition of those terms.  I would try cleaning your implementation first and getting others to reproduce the error before declaring it a bug.

The simplest work around is to convert your region $\Omega$ with a mesh produced by [`ToElementMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToElementMesh.html) and make the following additions/replacements:

```
(* Add this below Omega *)
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ω];
(* Replace Omega with mesh in your NDSolveValue *)
Tfun = NDSolveValue[pde, T, {r, z} ∈ mesh];
cfun = NDSolveValue[pde2, c, {r, z} ∈ mesh];
```

It is a bit of mystery, why `NDSolveValue` made the excursion outside the domain, $\Omega$ in the `cfun` case.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Manno You are welcome!  Definitely, your initial approach should have worked, but you will want to learn `ToElementMesh` to give you additional control over your mesh.